# Emacs replicating M-RET functionality of the org-mode in the rst-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, restructuredtext

In `org-mode`, typing `M-RET` at the end of a headline will create a new headline of the same level on a new line. Can I replicate this functionality in `rst-mode` (especially for lists)? Currently `M-RET` is not defined, and it would be great if I can just press `M-RET` and `rst-mode` would intelligently add another list header. For example,

```
- Item1 <M-RET>
```

renders

```
- Item1
-
```

automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the `rst.el` included in the particular version of Emacs I'm using is old. You can get the newer `rst.el` from the [Subversion repository](http://docutils.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/docutils/trunk/docutils/tools/editors/emacs/rst.el?view=log), and put it into your `load-path`. Then, you can make `rst-mode` specific key binding to `rst-insert-list`:

```
(eval-after-load "rst"
  '(progn 
     (define-key rst-mode-map (kbd "<M-RET>")
       (lambda ()
         (interactive)
         (rst-insert-list)))))
```

Then you can use `M-RET` to make new list.

Thanks for Stefan Merten for his [kind instructions](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=31577.1367759864%40eskebo.merten-home.homelinux.org&forum_name=docutils-develop) in the mailing list.

You can also take a look at the [Installation section](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/emacs.html#installation) of the Emacs Support for reStructuredText [documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/emacs.html).